# MongoDB refuse to start, operation not permitted

Tags: mongodb

When I try to run `mongod --dbpath=./data` I get the following error:

```
2017-09-20T21:47:55.720+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=20500 port=27017 dbpath=./data 64-bit host=debian
2017-09-20T21:47:55.721+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.11
2017-09-20T21:47:55.721+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 009580ad490190ba33d1c6253ebd8d91808923e4
2017-09-20T21:47:55.721+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
2017-09-20T21:47:55.721+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-09-20T21:47:55.721+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-09-20T21:47:55.721+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-09-20T21:47:55.721+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-09-20T21:47:55.721+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-09-20T21:47:55.722+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "./data" } }
2017-09-20T21:47:55.781+0200 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in ./data created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2017-09-20T21:47:55.802+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-09-20T21:47:55.894+0200 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (1) [1505936875:894516][20500:0x7f357e7c1cc0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: ./data/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2017-09-20T21:47:55.895+0200 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:1: Operation not permitted
2017-09-20T21:47:55.895+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 1: Operation not permitted, terminating
2017-09-20T21:47:55.895+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

The contents and permissions of the `./data` directory is as follows:

```
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  4096 Sep 20 05:11 .
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  4096 Sep 20 22:07 ..
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 36864 Sep 19 05:25 collection-0--661121965341019305.wt
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 36864 Sep 19 05:26 collection-0--9187569579836644431.wt
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 16384 Sep 19 05:24 collection-2--661121965341019305.wt
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     0 Sep 19 19:16 diagnostic.data
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 16384 Sep 19 05:24 index-0-7518289071480072689.wt
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 16384 Mar  1  2017 index-1-7518289071480072689.wt
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 36864 Sep 19 05:26 index-2-7518289071480072689.wt
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 36864 Sep 19 05:25 index-3-7518289071480072689.wt
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     0 Sep 20 05:12 journal
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 36864 Sep 19 05:24 _mdb_catalog.wt
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     0 Sep 20 05:11 mongod.lock
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 36864 Sep 19 05:26 sizeStorer.wt
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    95 Feb 23  2017 storage.bson
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    49 Feb 23  2017 WiredTiger
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  4096 Sep 19 05:24 WiredTigerLAS.wt
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf    21 Sep 20 04:49 WiredTiger.lock
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  1000 Sep 19 05:27 WiredTiger.turtle
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 61440 Sep 20 05:12 WiredTiger.wt
```

My user is in the `vboxsf` group.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error, or what I can do to fix this?

---

I should note that I'm running Debian inside Virtual Box on a Windows 8.1 host. The directory in question is a shared folder (hence the `vboxsf` group).

Comment: I have update query according to your log files. The real error is Cannot start server.

Comment: Have your tried your dbpath with repair mongo command such as "mongod --dbpath /data/db –repair" .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Know problem with mongod... It don't work with VirtualBox shared folders. dbPath must be local, NFS, SAN.. Anyway something what is mounted...

Comment: Seems like this is the problem. Rats.

Answer (score 7):

A summary of possible solutions are listed below for your convenience:

### [MongoDB Operation Not Permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41366402/1820861)

> MongoDB was working perfectly until one day it generated a lock file and stopped starting with the following error:

The corresponding accepted [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41371885/1820861) was:

> Assuming permissions are correct. It could be an selinux issue, try:
>
> ```
> setenforce 0
> ```
>
> then try to start the server. If the server starts, you will have to use semanage to set the proper context to the mongo data folder

### [Windows mounting /data/db](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/74)

> I'm trying to mount /data/db from my Windows dev PC but everytime I try, Mongo crashes as it seems to not have the right BUT :
>
> - I have changed the security parameters in windows to allow everyone to do everything (full access)
> - If I mount in a different directory, it works (the container launchs itself and I can write in my directory)

A possible explanation was:

> Found a link: VirtualBox Shared Folders are not supported by mongodb.

Apparently one user found a workaround and documented it as:

> It works using a volume which is created using docker volume create --name=myvolume
>   The volume name is used instead of the local path. It's just a workaround.
>   To be more precise the line I used in my case :
>
> ```
> docker volume create --name=mongodata
> docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v mongodata:/data/db --name=mymongo mongodb:3.3
> ```

### [Mongodb with volume doesn't work (Operation not permitted)](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/689)

The initial person writing the issue had already determined that it wouldn't work and was in search of a solution.

> Mongo docs says For example, HGFS and Virtual Box’s shared folders do not support this operation.
>   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#fsync-on-directories
>
> I wonder if it is possible to make work on current docker for windows.

There was a link in this case that recommeded tuning the mongodb storage engine:

> > Doesn't docker plan to implemnt something like this?
>
> No, not right now. You might be able to tweak the mongodb storage engine to work on an SMB share: https://forums.docker.com/t/issues-with-mongo-with-mounted-volume-for-data/15085/4

### Summary

There are multiple issues surrounding MongoDB and virtual servers on Microsoft Windows, so you might want to consider running your MongoDB in a *nix environment.

Comment: For me, it was the relative path in the volume mapping `-v mongodata:/data/db`. When I changed to an absolute local path `-v ${PWD}/mongodata:/data/db` it worked.

Comment: @Amnon For me it was the opposite way: I have to replace the absolute path in volume mapping

Answer (score 1):

```
2017-09-20T21:47:55.802+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-09-20T21:47:55.894+0200 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (1) [1505936875:894516][20500:0x7f357e7c1cc0], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: ./data/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
2017-09-20T21:47:55.895+0200 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:1: Operation not permitted
2017-09-20T21:47:55.895+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 1: Operation not permitted, terminating
2017-09-20T21:47:55.895+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Mr. @o01, I have gone through your error log actually the real error is Cannot start server. The default storage engine `wiredTiger` is not available with this build of `mongod`.

what is your installation `mongod` server path from there you run the below mention command.

Please specify a different storage engine explicitly.

> e.g. mongod.exe --storageEngine=mmapv1

for your further ref [Storage Engines](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/storage-engines/)